# Setting CSS files to private?

Tags: html, css, database, security, web

Is there any way to keep tools like SiteSucker or PageSucker from downloading CSS files from the site I build? I know that if you try to pull something like digg.com, you won't get a single CSS file.

Is this a database security feature? Is this just simply a matter of relative paths vs absolute paths?

Comment: what you want is impossible. if your css files can't be downloaded, then your site is going to be completely unstyled. there is **NO** 100% reliable method of detecting a download as "grab this file so I my browser can properly display your site" v.s. "grab this file so I can steal your css".

Comment: @MarcB So I suppose the best way to go about it would just be to put my code through an obfuscater?

Comment: @MarcB I wouldn't say it's *impossible*... if they have an identifiable user agent he could choose not to serve a CSS file to them.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: And UA's are so very hard to forge...

Comment: @MarcB that wasn't my point. Wasn't implying it was reliable for failsafe, just that it isn't impossible.

Comment: @hesham8: not really. the raw css might be obfusated, but you can't change "background-image" or "color" to something different. all the obfuscator can do is change class/id names. and even then, it's trivial to use a dom inspector to see what's applying where. rightclick something on a page, inspect element, "oh, that's class .asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"

Comment: you can also use referrer header. though not sure if all browsers implement this feature for css correctly. but still it's not a real security - the css still can be downloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its impossible. but you can use css compressor to compress your css to dificulty other to stole your code.

https://csscompressor.net/

http://cssminifier.com/

its a commom practice use compress.

Good work.

Comment: BUt then you could just use a de-compressor to expand the file back to how it was? http://unminify.com/